# Why should I use @extend in SCSS?

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

In Sass, I could find I can use '@extend' with '@mixin'.
But from the code, I got curious what's the advantage of using extend.
If we know which 'classes' exactly what do we have to use, we can just use two classes, not extend and make another class.

In my opinion, if we just use two classes, not making multiple extends, code would be shorter and we can save memory. What can I think of the advantage is it's just more easy to see on 'CSS output', but usually people just check SCSS file, not CSS code output.

Isn't it just better to use two separate classes instead of using multiple extends? What is the main advantage of using '@mixin'?

Comment: https://vanseodesign.com/css/sass-mixin-or-extend/

Comment: `@extend` allows you to group selectors which share the same styles. `@mixin` will duplicate the styles.

Comment: @Arkellys Thanks for the answer, but I know how it works. Eventually, using two classes and make one alternative class with 'extend' works equal. Just got curious what's the advantage of using it? I thought there must be some reason, but couldn't find it.

Comment: The advantage is that you don't have to repeat your styles and/or your selectors that's it. When you have several elements sharing the same styles, you can either create an helper class that you will apply on all of these elements, or you can use `@extend` so your selectors will be grouped and you don't have to repeat them in your code. The [Sass docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend) also gives others examples of useful uses of `@extend`. In the end it just make your life easier.

Comment: The advantage of ```@extend``` is, suppose there is a scenario, where you have created some generic classes, and at one place you just need to have similar style with some modification into it. At this point you wont use ```@mixin``` since you need to inherit the properties and add additional changes into it without disturbing parent class

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It helps you write DRY code quickly. @extend can be very useful when used properly.

It allows a selector to extend the styles of another selector, essentially providing a form of sub-classing. @extend works by combining selectors into a single comma-separated selector.

I.e. -

```
.A {
    font-size: 1rem;
    color:red;
}

.a{
    @extend .A;
    line-height: normal;
   }


Which outputs:

.A,.a {
   font-size: 1rem;
    color:red;
}

.a{
   line-height: normal;
}
```

Comment: One downside of the @extend is that if you have some hierarchy of classes and use the relational selectors you have to extend each of the relations. This is super uncomfortable when for example you extending 3rd party libraries

Comment: yes agree  on this !

Comment: Sorry but this makes no sense and wasteful as CSS naturally inherits text-based properties. Everything in your example could be added to one parent selector and thousands of children down the tree would inherit them. You then add styles to override them as needed not repeat the same ones in SASS. This is why SASS people fail to understand basic CSS and end up making a huge mess.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of important issues with extends to keep in mind:

- they change the order of your CSS rules and re-group them often awkwardly which can have unintentional issues down the road
- they are less performant than Mixins when your Sass is minified and gzipped.

Great article detailing these issues by Harry Roberts: ["Mixins for Better Performance"](https://csswizardry.com/2016/02/mixins-better-for-performance/)